I am using hls player in Angular Web App and i am using same code in Amazon Fire Stick Web App. But code is not working properly on fire stick app
I am using below Angular Code.
if (Hls.isSupported()) {
          if (this.hlsRef) this.hlsRef.detachMedia();
          this.hlsRef = new Hls({ debug: false });
          this.hlsRef.loadSource(videoUrl);
          this.hlsRef.attachMedia(video);
          this.hlsRef.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, () => video.play());
          this.hlsRef.on(Hls.Events.ERROR, (event: any, data: any) => {
            console.error('HLS error:', data);
          });
        }

I am not getting any error but .m3u8 video link is not playing in Amazon Fire Stick. Same video link is playing fine in Angular Web App on Chrome. There is no difference in code.
The issue of not playing .m3u8 video is happening only 1st time. After i navigate in app and again try to play same .m3u8 video link, it starts to play.
Please help me friends.
Thank you.
